# Cannot install .ipa file using Appium

Tags: java, ios, xcode, appium

I am working with iOS version 10 and Xcode 8.

When I am using Appium to install the `.ipa` file on my phone I got an error:

> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error:
>   Installing
>   /var/folders/38/_j5rw9g93tn2mk_ypg0b12gc0000gn/T/2016815-20850-vgqq3k/Payload/MPM.app
>   failed

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution even i am facing same issue.

Comment: I solved it. Are you trying to install the app using appium desktop app or from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
```

I was getting the same issue but it got resolved. This is related to the `ideviceinstaller`.